# How to document Salesforce user profiles - SOQL queries to pull data

Tags: soql, permissions, profile, excel

I want to document and **compare user profiles quickly without having to flip between profiles in Salesforce**. I typically use the Permcomparator tool but this would be a file that all teammates would have access to in my org.

Has anyone created such a document? What data points did you find most useful?

At a minimum I'd like to document for each profile:

- App Permissions
- Object Permissions
- System Permissions
- Custom Permissions

Were there specific **SOQL queries** you used to create profile documentation? I'm struggling with how to set this up in Excel, to be honest.